# Cannot access internal android storage..?

Tags: android, android-file

I have to access this file: file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1381243874374.jpg

It should be in the internal storage.. but if I give to Android this path, it can't load the file. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: internal `storage`, not memory. memory != storage.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Question fixed :)

Comment: No, that is in what is considered the "external" storage, even if is located in flash chips permanently soldered to the board rather than a removable micro SD card.  Also, that's an explicit path to a location valid only in *some* android versions.  You really should discover the applicable mount point at runtime using the External Storage APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed this like that:

```
    String[] split = path.split("sdcard/");
    path = split[1];

    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    path = sd.getAbsolutePath() + '/' + path;
```

Comment: if 'path' is a Uri just do File sd = new File(uri.getPath());

Comment: @dymmeh - an important part of what is going on here is the runtime discovery of the *actual* external storage base path (mount point) on the specific device where it is executing

Comment: @ChrisStratton I assumed he was getting the path at runtime so it should be pointing to the correct storage location. If that's not true then, yes, my point is wrong.